# How can I know, when item add to Table (libgdx)

Tags: android, libgdx

How can I know, when an item is added to a table in libGDX? I have a ScrollPane in which there is a Table, and I have a scroll ScrollPane in Bottom. When I do so:

```
table.add(button()).left().padTop(5).expandX().maxWidth(game.w - 10);
    }
    tableMessages.row();        
    scrollPane.setScrollY(table.getHeight());   //I have scroll ScrollPane in bottom
```

But scroll on the penultimate element, rather than the last. That is program not see that was added one more item. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem quite a while ago. Here is how I solved it, although Im not sure if you need every line but it should point you in the right direction.

```
    scrollPane.scrollTo(0, scrollPane.getScrollBarHeight(), 0, 0);
    scrollPane.setScrollPercentY(1f);
    scrollPane.setScrollY(scrollPane.getScrollY());
    scrollPane.updateVisualScroll();
```